# Unicode vs encoding python text processing

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I am doing some text processing with text scraped from the web. I was thinking of decoding the raw text before

```
raw_html=  raw_html.decode("iso-8859-1")
```

And later encode to UTF so I would not have problems with the encoding...

```
raw_html=  raw_html.encode("UTF-8")
```

The issue is that despite knowing the web page encoding I keep getting errors in the decode part...

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 302: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I will be dealing with many languages, but not so many web pages (so my idea of manually setting the encode). And I would like to be able to convert all the languages (english, french, spanish, Portuguese) to a common base to work with. What would you suggest?

Comment: You are encoding to Latin-1, not UTF..

Comment: How did you read `raw_html`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just edited for the UTF-8 in the encoding. It was a mistake when posting... The raw_html was given to me as a text file... I was looking in the HTML source code for the same site and my HTML seems to have passed through some form of encoding/decodind as some characters are different... ist it possible to undo that back to the HTML original encoding? and then apply my code?

Comment: Without seeing any samples that is impossible to diagnose. You could have used the wrong codec or the file could have been reencoded with a wrong codec. The latter is often repairable, but I am talking in general terms. That would be a new question however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `raw_html.decode()` gives you an **encoding** exception, then it was **already** Unicode:

```
>>> u'é'.decode('latin1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

because Python 2 implicitly first tries to encode (with the default ASCII codec) when trying to 'decode' Unicode values.

Comment: Thanks! sorry... just realized the mistake... when I try to encode it to UTF-8 i get the following error: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal. Is it because some characters can not be encoded in UTF-8? In this case it would make more sense to work the text in unicode, no? Thanks for help!!

Comment: Work with Unicode where possible. Decoding Unicode makes no sense, you already decoded to Unicode, after all. Check with `print type(raw_html)`.

Comment: sorry to bother.. but it is driving me crazy... Does Python encodes the loaded text in some format? I am trying to match the euro symbol (€) by its unicode (\u20ac) which I see in the text file but it does not seems to recognize it when I import... any ideas of what I might be doing wrong? I am using r'\\u20ac?\b' to match it and it worked well if I manually input the string as a variable...

Comment: Make that a new question, perhaps? Why are you escaping the Unicode escape and not using a `ur'...'` raw Unicode value?

Comment: Thanks Matijin! I will formulate it as a new question.